# SAL annotations for returning reference counted objects

Tags: c, sal

I'm trying to use SAL annotations to guard against certain possible errors when using reference counted objects. Annotations specific for this use case are not available (as far as I can tell), but using the [locking annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/annotating-locking-behavior?view=msvc-160) could work.

```c
typedef struct RefCnt;

void
Reference(_Inout_ _Acquires_lock_(*_Curr_) RefCnt *R);

void
Unreference(_Inout_ _Releases_lock_(*_Curr_) RefCnt *R);
```

This will ensure that for each call to `Reference` there is a call to `Unreference`, which is exactly what I want.

However, this leaves some gaps. If I have a reference counted object and I have some way of getting that object I want to receive a warning if I'm not unreferencing it:

```c
typedef struct
{
    RefCnt R;
} Object;

Object global_obj;

Object *
GetObject(void)
{
    Reference(&global_obj.R);
    return &global_obj;
}
```

This will trigger a warning: `warning C26165: Possibly failing to release lock 'global_obj.R' in function 'GetObject'.`, which is to be expected. I can annotate the `GetObject` function so it becomes: `_Acquires_lock_(_Curr_->R) Object *GetObject(void)`. This solves the problem, but I'm probably introducing a new one because I'm not getting any warnings for code like this:

```c
void
Test(void)
{
    Object *o = GetObject();
    // The reference counter is never reset, this is a leak, I should get a warning
}
```

If I'm using output parameters it works, so `void GetObject(_At_(*_Curr_, _Acquires_lock_(_Curr_->R)) Object **O)` is a solution, but I'm trying to improve an existing API that directly returns the object, so doing this change is something I'd like to avoid.

Is there a way of doing this or is this something that SAL can not express?